# How to propagate QGraphicsItemGroup mouse events to child elements?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qt6, qgraphicsitemgroup

Is it possible to propagate `QGraphicsItemGroup` mouse events to child added items?

[setHandlesChildEvents(false)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem-obsolete.html#setHandlesChildEvents) is deprecated, and I don't want to use it.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```cpp
class MoveItemBase : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem;

bool sceneEvent(QEvent* event) override
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick) {
        propagateSceneEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    return QGraphicsItemGroup::sceneEvent(event);
}

void propagateSceneEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    for (QGraphicsItem* child : childItems()) {
        MoveItemBase* widget = static_cast<MoveItemBase*>(child);  
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent(widget, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know and found, there is no direct alternative to [setHandlesChildEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem-obsolete.html#setHandlesChildEvents).

I did however find a workaround in this thread on [Qt Center Forum](https://www.qtcentre.org): [setHandlesChildEvents() obsolete?](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/66799-setHandlesChildEvents()-obsolete), where it was suggested to use [QGraphicsItem::installSceneEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter), which says:

> Installs an event filter for this item on filterItem, causing all events for this item to first pass through filterItem's [sceneEventFilter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneEventFilter) function.
>
> ...
>
> An item can only filter events for other items in the same scene.

Based on these findings, I made a generic example to implement that:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

//class of the item used as an event filter for other graphic items
class FilterItem :  public QGraphicsLineItem
{
public:
    FilterItem (QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
    {}

protected:
    bool sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem *watched, QEvent *event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Handling child graphics item event here";
            return true;
        }

        return QGraphicsItem::sceneEventFilter(watched,event);
    }
};

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView v;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    FilterItem *filterItem = new FilterItem;
    QGraphicsRectItem *targetItem = scene.addRect(QRect(10, 10, 50, 50));

    //the filter item has to be added to the same scene
    scene.addItem(filterItem);
    //install it on the targeted item
    targetItem->installSceneEventFilter(filterItem);

    v.setScene(&scene);
    v.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```